# Simple In-Browser Timeline

Tags: javascript, visualization, timeline

I want to make a tool for a game server that will read the connect/disconnect logs and present them in a visually appealing way.
The effect I am looking for is similar to this mock-up (Excuse the 'Programmer Art')

Here is my image:

[image]

Where the coloured bars show the time the user was connected to the server.

[DHX Timeline View](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) is the closest I've come to a viable solution for an in-browser solution.
Simile, Mashi, Verite and a few others seem a bit too complex for what I want.

Are there any scripts that can do what I need?
Has anyone any experience with this kind of thing?
Would it be better to build one? If so, how? (I'm totally open to learning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Timeline](http://almende.github.com/chap-links-library/timeline.html) seems to be very close to what I want.

[Here](http://almende.github.com/chap-links-library/js/timeline/examples/example15_mobile.html) is an example that seems to fulfill my requirements.

Comment: The Timeline library above is a long time abandoned project. In spite of beautiful examples, it is almost no implementable in a classic way as a frontend UX component since it requires integration with GWT - Google Web Toolkit. In other words, source code for timeline must be written in JAVA and then compiled via GWT into client Javascript code. Thus setup is complex. Moreover, it looks like loaded google/jsapi is blocking loading cross site scripts. `http://visjs.org` library claims to be project successor.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Timeline Portfolio](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/04/timeline-portfolio/) - it's cross browser, it has a tutorial to accompany it, and is very easy to integrate into a site.

Oh, and its also [pretty beautiful](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/04/timeline-portfolio/).

Comment: Having a poke around now, seems a bit over the top though.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what I need. I can't seems to make separate rows for each user.
The, um, _timeline-min.js_ file is like impossible to read.